# Bézout and products in algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, zariski-topology

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group -- be it a Lie group or a group of Lie type. Let $V$, $W$ be subvarieties of $G$. Of course, $V\cap W$ is also a variety (not necessarily irreducible) and $V\cdot W^{-1}$ is a constructible set. It is easy to see that $\dim(\overline{V\cdot W^{-1}}) = \dim(V)+\dim(W)-\dim(V\cap a W)$ for $a\in V\cap W$ generic. By Bézout, we know that the degree $\deg(V\cap a W)$ of $V\cap a W$ (meaning the sum of the degrees of its components) is at most $\deg(V)\cdot \deg(W)$.

Is it always the case that $\deg(V \cap a W) \cdot \deg(\overline{V\cdot W^{-1}}) \leq \deg(V)\cdot \deg(W)$, for $a\in \overline{V\cdot W^{-1}}$ generic?

If not, is that the case under some sort of generic conditions, or, say, for $W = g V g^{-1}$ and $g\in G$ generic?

Reason why such a thing might be plausible: if $\dim(V) + \dim(W)\geq \dim(G)$, then, generically, $\overline{V\cdot W}$ is the entire group, and, while $\deg(G)$ is not in general $1$ for $G$ seen as a subvariety of $M(n)\sim \mathbb{A}^{n^2}$, the degree of $G$ "relative" to itself is in some sense $1$ (of course we would need to formalise that notion; the point is that that's how it works out in further applications of Bézout's theorem, in a trivial sense, in so far as, for $V\subset G$, $\deg(V\cap G) = \deg(V) \cdot 1$). If $\dim(V)+\dim(W)<\dim(G)$, then, generically, the intersection $V\cap W$ is empty, and non-generically, Bézout may not be tight.

Comment: The claim that $\dim(\overline{V\cdot W})$ has dimension $\dim(V)+\dim(W)-\dim(V\cap W)$ is not true. For instance, typically when $V=W$ (say, for a general enough curve in the plane), we have $\dim(V\cdot V)=2\dim(V)$ (and not $=\dim(V)$). For the rest of the question, I'm not sure what you call degree.

Comment: Hm, you are right. For the rest of the question - let us go with "sum of the degrees of irreducible components of maximal dimension" as the definition of the degree of reducible variety.

Comment: What {\em is} the case is that $\dim(\overline{V\cdot W})$ has dimension $\dim(V)+\dim(W)-\dim(V\cap a W^{-1})$ for $a\in \overline{V\cdot W}$ generic (or for $a$ in the image of a generic point of $V\times W$ under the multiplication map, which is the same).

Comment: [you can write italics/boldface in comments surrounding with star sign, resp double star ($*$blah$*$ yields *blah* and $**$blah$**$ yields **blah**)]

Comment: What is the degree?

Comment: I just said that above!

Comment: ... though I think Bézout is still true if you define the degree of a reducible variety to be the sum of the degrees of *all* irreducible components. Yup, see the Fulton reference in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42127/generalization-of-bezouts-theorem

Comment: Laurent Moret-Bailly's question is still pertinent. Into which affine or projective space are you embedding your varieties? "Degree" is not defined without choosing such an embedding.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of everything as sitting inside $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$, since we can see $G$ as a subgroup of $\GL_n$. At the same time, I agree that it would be helpful to have some definition of degree of subvarieties of $G$ that is in some sense relative to $G$ (in such a way that the degree of $G$ relative to itself is $1$).

Comment: This starts with the choice of a faithful representation of $G$. Then ''degree'' will mean ''degree of the closure in $\mathbb P^{n^2}$. Requiring $\deg G=1$ will then require dividing by $\deg G$ so that degree is now a rational number.

Comment: More substantively, I'm confused by the statement ''if $\deg(V)+\deg(W)\ge\deg(G)$, then, generically, $\overline{V⋅W}$ is the entire group". If $V,W$ are curves of high degree and $\dim G\ge 3$ this is false if $V.W$ denotes the image in $G$ of $V\times W$ under the multiplication morphism.

Comment: On the first comment by inkwell: well, sure, let us fix a faithful representation of $G$. On the second comment: there is something I am not seeing. For generic $V$ and $W$ of dimension $d\geq \deg(G)/2$ (say), surely, $V\cap a W$ be $0$-dimensional for $a$ generic? In that case, $\overline{V\cdot W^{-1}}$ should indeed be of dimension $\deg(G)$.

Comment: Oh, I see - I said $\deg(V)+\deg(W)\geq \deg(G)$ when I meant $\dim(V)+\dim(W)\geq \dim(G)$. My bad.